# Hadoop map reduce program error when running from Eclipse

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop map reduce programming. I have tried with a sample code of wordcount and run it from Eclipse . When I have run it from Eclipse in local mode it has run successfully also when I built a jar and run it on hadoop it run successfully. But whenever I am trying to run it from Eclipse on Hadoop it is keep getting failed with this error. Though there is no problem with accessing the hdfs location because every time it fails it is creating the output directory in hdfs. I am really running out of a clue here. Please help.

```
14/08/09 13:42:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/08/09 13:42:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/08/09 13:42:27 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/09 13:42:28 WARN conf.Configuration: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
14/08/09 13:42:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201408091257_0004
14/08/09 13:42:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/08/09 13:42:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:42:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:43:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:43:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:43:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:43:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408091257_0004_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201408091257_0004
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=8
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=8
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=143034
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/08/09 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1372)
    at test.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at test.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:51)
```

## Code

### WordCount.java

```
package test;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf(
          "Usage: %s [generic options] <input dir> <output dir>\n", getClass()
              .getSimpleName());
      ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.out);
      return -1;
    }

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName(this.getClass().getName());

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    conf.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);

    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:8021");

    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    conf.setJarByClass(test.WordCount.class);

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}
```

### SumReducer.java

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class SumReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

  @Override
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException {

    int wordCount = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
      IntWritable value = values.next();
      wordCount += value.get();
    }
    if (wordCount < 100)
    {
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(wordCount));
    }
  }
}
```

### WordMapper.java

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException {
    String s = value.toString();
    for (String word : s.split("\\W+")) {
      if (word.length() > 0) {
        output.collect(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? Otherwise it will be hard to answer

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look. Kindly let me know if I am missing out on anything?

Comment: Can you try with this code and see whether it is running add extra configurations to connect your cluster: http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/hadoop-wordcount-example-in-detail.html

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on your Project, Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Select Libraries tab, Click Add External JARs and copy all the Required JAR files in your hadoop directory. I guess, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi I have added all the necessary jars and moreover when I have run it on locally or by creating a jar on hadoop it has ran successfully but it is keep getting failed by the following error when ever I am trying to run it on Hadoop from Eclipse. Though it is creating output directory in the hdfs location but not been able to execute the job in a successful completion.

Comment: the problem is not with missing libraries or the code. It works when bundled as jar. But, inside eclipse it has a problem. I have the same problem, and added all the libraries